# make header menu a fixed position(theme tesseract)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make the header menu ontop of the tesseract theme (http://tyler.com/ ) a **fixed position**, so that if you scroll down one can access all menu elements from any postion on the site.

I have tried a few things and always added `position:fixed;` to a few css classes of the theme, but nothing happened.

I would be glad, if you could help me out with this issue. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check my answer. I just verified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this code from `position: relative` to `position: fixed`

```
.home .site-header.no-header-image {
  left: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
}
```

Now to avoid the top content getting hidden:

```
.home .site-content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

**Output**
[image: Output]

Comment: How can I do that? I dont know any php. If I add this to the style.css file nothing happens.

Comment: Go to style.css, search for this code and edit only the relative text to fixed. Best way to do this is using Child themes since you are using WordPress.

Comment: It is in site-banner.css `http://tyler.com/wp-content/themes/TESSERACT-Merge-Test/css/site-banner.css`

Comment: thank you so much... it's working. one last issue: the backgroundbar ontop got smaller now. which class should I edit to get it back to the original size?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
.<youClassName>{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

This should fix your menu to the top and it will follow you on scrolling.

Comment: which class in this case? site-navigation? or should i add it to all the classes included in the "top area"

Comment: The position and top just need to be added to whatever class is controlling your menu.

Answer (score 0):

remove `position: relative;`

add

```
.home .site-header.no-header-image {
  position: fixed;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add position fixed to a div not in every element

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5h64w0j/)

**HTML**

```
<div id = "menu">
    <ul class = "main">
        <li>
            Home
        </li>
        <li>
            About
        </li>
        <li>
            Contact
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id = "content">

    CONTENT CONTENT
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#menu {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #0088cc;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 2%;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Rick, this is not he wanted.