# Make the header menu a fixed position for all pages

Tags: css, wordpress

I use a WP template with a `position: relative` default header. I've edited`style.css` with the code below ([from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380465/make-header-menu-a-fixed-positiontheme-tesseract)):

```
.home .site-header.no-header-image {
  left: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
}
.home .site-content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Now header on home page is fixed indeed but it only works for home page, so I've added this to `style.css`:

```
.site-header.no-header-image {
  left: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  }
.site-content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Header is now fixed on all pages but content of pages is aligned from top of the page and not from header. I've tried to change padding from `.site-content` to 120/150/180 or any padding but it doesn't affect the padding of the content which does not start from the header anymore.

**So here is my issue : having pages content to be aligned from header and header being `position: fixed;` on all pages.**

There must be something I'm missing obviously and tried lots of css modification but can't figure out what's wrong. Also, I've tried the solution [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107730/make-tesseract-theme-header-fixed-for-all-pages) which is supposedly the same problem as mine but it doesn't give any result and header stays relative  with this fix.

Thanks.

Comment: Set top: 0; maybe?

Comment: you could achieve this with javascript: setting the header menu fixed on top of the page when after you scroll down . 
Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2907906/4375054

Comment: @Mike I tried from 0 to 200, nothing happened.

Comment: @fabio thanks but I have quesiton regarding this:

- Is it only possible through jquery ? no walkthrough using css only ?

- Admitting you have to use jquery, I have to give my header the correspondant class which will be trigerred with jquery. How am I suppose to set this class to header ?

Comment: margin-top your body to the height of the fixed menu? Do you have a live website so we can take a look?

Comment: margin-top the body of 60px (my header width) will result in having the header margin-top 60px as well so it doesn't work. I don't really have a link, I'm working on a dev site. but links to the 2 threads from my orignial post is exactly what I need to achieve since all this is based from tesseract theme.

Comment: set fixed element to top: 0 at the same time!

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused here, can I post my style.css below ?

Comment: Back on this, I'm still missing the right combination. Is it ok iif I post my style.css here ?